# OpenERP - NotImplementedError on evaluating result of object.browse(...)

Tags: python, orm, odoo

I'm browsing for records, then I would like to perform specific code if browsing return results.

Here is my code :

```
sub = self.pool.get('subscription.subscription').search(cr,uid,[('partner_id','=',partner.id),('active','=',True)])
if sub:
    mtp.send_mail(cr, uid, level.email_template_id.id, partner.id, context=ctx)
```

But it does not work, when evaluating the `if` condition, an exception is raised :

```
NotImplementedError: Iteration is not allowed on browse_record(res.partner, 15918)
```

I don't understand, because i'm not iterating over the result by checking if a result exist, neither calling the `__iter__` method.

Thank you for your help

Cheers

Comment: show your code. i mean .py file or that particular method which consist this condition.

Comment: yep, some more code would be very helpful to help you :-)

Answer (score 1):

In general cases the problem is that you are invoking browse method with only one ID, not a list of IDs, so the return value is only one record, not a list of records, so is not iterable.

Comment: Correct, but how do you check for that?

Answer (score 0):

*ids* can be wither a list of ids or a numeric id.

In the latter case, *browse* returns a single record, non iterable, instead of an iterable collection of records.

The solution is to make sure ids is a list.

Add this after method definition.

```
if not isinstance(ids, list):
    ids = [ids]
```